# How can I remove Time Range Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

In Kibana 5.2.2 there is this time range filter:
[image]

I have some documents without a timestamp on a type.
Since there is no option 'all time', I cannot see those documents.
Is there an option to disable this time range filter?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to fix your data, unfortunately, and set some kind of dummy timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to uncheck `Index contains time-based events` when creating the index pattern.

For more information: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/connect-to-elasticsearch.html

Comment: This is not possible in Kibana 5.2.2. I upgraded to 5.5.2 and now it is possible to not chose any default-timestamp. Thank you!

Comment: Great - for anyone else coming across this. In previous versions you can uncheck the "Index contains time-based events" checkbox.